How to change existing tracking icon to a random place in repeating intervals?
I want to test updating location by creating an interval that updates the tracking icon to random location given longitude and latitude.
Until now I changed the tracking icon to a new location on click, and then I had the pixel from the singleclick event and I could use forEachFeatureAtPixel:
    map.on('singleclick', function (e) {
      map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
        if (f === trackingIcon) {
          const randomLon = generateRandomLon();
          const randomLat = generateRandomLat();
          f.getGeometry().setCoordinates(fromLonLat([randomLon, randomLat]))
        }
      });
    });

But now I want to do it randmoly, not on click, something like:
    const interval = setInterval((e) => {
      map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {        
          const randomLon = generateRandomLon();
          const randomLat = generateRandomLat();
          console.log(randomLonLat);
          f.getGeometry().setCoordinates(fromLonLat([randomLon, randomLat]))
        
      });
    }, 3000);

But that won't work because e is not a singleclick event that has the pixel as a property.
Which method can be used instead, to replace the existing tracking icon in this case?
That's how I create the map initially (with React and Nextjs):
function Map() {
  const trackingIcon = new Feature({
    geometry: initialPoint
  });

  trackingIcon.setStyle(
    new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        color: '#DC143C',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        src: 'icons/dot.svg',
      }),
    }),
  );

  const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: [trackingIcon],
  });

  const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: vectorSource,
  });

  const tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM()
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([34.956433, 32.795214]),
        zoom: 14,
      }),
    });

...

